# how to save video in mysql? using Blob or using path of the file?

Tags: c#, mysql

What is the code for saving the path of video in mysql? Is it Blob or Varbinary or Varchar or Text?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are the requirements? There are reasons for doing either.

Comment: Im gonna retrieve the video from mysql then play it in c#
how do I save the path file... is it text or blob?

Comment: Are you retrieving the video file or the path to the video file from the database? Which is it?

Comment: the path to the video

Comment: Well, that would be a string than, wouldn't it.

Comment: thank you..
Varchar in Mysql right? it would be like this C:\Desktop\vid.mp4

Comment: almost certainly more efficient to store the file on disk, and just store the path to it in the DB as a varchar. Video files are generally quite large...storing and retrieving that as blob data will be slow, I suspect. A path is just a piece of text, so varchar will be fine. Blob would be for the actual binary video data, which I think would be a bad idea, as I just explained.

Answer (score 0):

You should use varchar because you save database memory. Blob is using much bigger memory for storing. So good practice is if your path, or text you enter in data field is no longer then 255 characters (and in this case it isn't) you shouldn't use blob

Comment: Right answer, but memory use isn't really the real reason for this - blob data is binary, why would you store a piece of text (a filepath) as binary? The real reason for using varchar is simply that it's the correct data type for storing text.

Comment: I agree with you @ADyson

Comment: Ok well if you amend your answer to use that reason, you can have an upvote from me :-)